# How get metric for elasticsearch node in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

[Aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics-cluster-metrics) provides several metric in cloud watch about es cluster. But how get CPU loading for concrete ES nodes? E.g. it shows, say 40% CPU loading, which is average number for all cluster, but how get such information for all nodes in ES cluster? It there a way to get `EC2` `InstanceId` from elasticsearch cluster and then get cloud watch CPU by `InstanceId`?

Other variants?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [amazon elasticsearch service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/).
The supported [cluster metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics-cluster-metrics) `CPUUtilization` is as mentioned in OP max/average all nodes.

If you require to monitor individual node cpu-utilization one workaround is to use elasticsearch _nodes api

`get _nodes/_all/stats/os,jvm,process`

Invoke the api and sample this data at frequent intervals and publish it to cloudwatch or other monitoring tool

See this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) on publishing custom metrics to cloudwatch.

Comment: did this not help ?